# Retain ordering of text data when vectorizing

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, nltk

I am attempting to write a machine learning algorithm with `scikit-learn` that parses text and classifies it based on training data.

The example for using text data, taken directly from the `scikit-learn` documentation, uses a `CountVectorizer` to generate a sparse array for how many times each word appears.

```
>>> from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
>>> count_vect = CountVectorizer()
>>> X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(twenty_train.data)
```

Unfortunately, this does not take into account any ordering of the phrases. It is possible to use larger `ngrams` (`CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(min, max))`) to look at specific phrases, but this increases the number of features rapidly and isn't even that great.

Is there a good way of dealing with ordered text in another way? I'm definitely open to using a natural language parser (`nltk`, `textblob`, etc.) along with `scikit-learn`.

Comment: The bag-of-words + Naive Bayes model works pretty well in some contexts. Are you doing binary classification or multi-class?

Comment: @bpachev I'm starting with binary classification, but I'd like to get to multi-class, once my binary classifier is working decently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about [word2vec embedding?](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/tutorials/word2vec/index.html) It is a neural network based embedding of words into vectors, and takes context into account. This could provide a more sophisticated set of features for your classifier.

One powerful python library for natural language processing with a good word2vec implementation is [gensim](http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/). Gensim is built to be very scalable and fast, and has advanced text processing capabilities.  Here is a quick outline on how to get started:

**Installing**

Just do `easy_install -U gensim` or `pip install --upgrade gensim`.

**A simple word2vec example**

```
import gensim

documents = [['human', 'interface', 'computer'],
 ['survey', 'user', 'computer', 'system', 'response', 'time'],
 ['eps', 'user', 'interface', 'system'],
 ['system', 'human', 'system', 'eps'],
 ['user', 'response', 'time'],
 ['trees'],
 ['graph', 'trees'],
 ['graph', 'minors', 'trees'],
 ['graph', 'minors', 'survey']]

model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(documents, min_count=1)
print model["survey"]
```

This will output the vector that "survey" maps to, which you could use for a feature input to your classifier.

Gensim has a lot of other capabilities, and it is worth getting to know it better if you're interested in Natural Language Processing.